# Isabelle recursive function

Tags: recursion, isabelle

I have the following recursive function that creates a list of 0s (i.e. [0,...,0]) in **VDM**. How can this be ***translated*** to **Isabelle** using *fun-where*?

VDM:

```
NewList: nat1 * seq of nat -> seq of nat
NewList(n, l) == 
    if len l = n then l
    else NewList(n, l ^ [0])
-- pre/post-conditions excluded here
```

My attempts are horribly wrong due to my lack of understanding of Isabelle (but below at least proves that I tried...).

Isabelle:

```
fun
  NewList:: "N ⇒ (VDMNat VDMSeq) ⇒ (VDMNat VDMSeq)"
where
  "NewList n [] = NewList n [0]"
| "NewList n [x] = (if len [x] = n then [x] else NewList n (x#[0]))"
| "NewList n (x # xs) = (if len (x # xs) = n then (x # xs) else NewList n ((x # xs) # [(0::VDMNat)]))"
```

*The data types VDMNat and VDMSeq are defined in some library. Please ignore the VDMNat and VDMSeq for now - any sort of implementation using Isabelle's data types are welcome (at least it would provide a good reference for my implementation). Please refer to the VDM code for the data types intended.

Could you also please explain what `x`, `xs`, and `(x # xs)` are referring to? I've seen this in several recursive function examples (though none helps me).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is what you are really asking: how to write a function that - given a number `n` - returns a list of `n` zeros? (It seems like it in your attempt). Otherwise, what is `scoreboard` in your VDM example. And which library are you referring to for the definition of VMDNat and VDMSeq?

Comment: Apologies - `scoreboard` is supposed to be l (now corrected). Yes, that's what I need: returning a sequence of n zeros. I'm trying to translate my VDM function to Isabelle. Please ignore the VDMNat and VDMSeq for now - any sort of implementation using Isabelle's data types are welcome (at least it would provide a good reference for my implementation). Thanks, Chris!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `x` and `xs` are variables. When definiting recursive functions on lists, these are often used to denote the first element of the list (`x`) and the remaining list (`xs`). The expression `x # xs` means ‘`x` prepended to the list `xs`’, and that is the reason why `(x # xs) # [0]` in your question does not work: `x # xs` is a list and `[0]` is also a list. You would have to do `x # xs @ [0}`, where `@` is the function to concatenate two lists.

Now, to your function: My interpretation of your function definition is that you have a natural number `n` and a list `l` and want to pad the list `l` with zeros at the back up to length `n`.

However, when the list `l` is of length `> n` to begin with, your function does not terminate. You would have to think about what to do in that case.

Here are my suggestions for what you could do:

## Possibility 1

Change the `= n` to a `≥ n`. Then you can prove termination of the function by looking at

```
function new_list :: "nat ⇒ nat list ⇒ nat list" where
  "new_list n l = (if length l ≥ n then l else new_list n (l @ [0]))"
by pat_completeness auto
termination by (relation "measure (λ(n, l). n - length l)") auto
```

However, proving theorems about this will probably get ugly. I would therefore urge you to do something like the following two possibilities. Ideally, use functions from Isabelle's standard library, because there is usually good automation setup for them. Alternatively, define your own small building blocks (like `take` and `replicate`) for your datatypes and prove reusable facts on them and combine them to do what you want. A ‘monolithic’ function definition like yours is difficult to work with when doing proofs.

## Possibility 2

Use the builtin function `replicate`, which takes a natural number `n` and an element and returns a list of `n` times that element:

```
definition new_list :: "nat ⇒ nat list ⇒ nat list" where
  "new_list n l = l @ replicate (n - length l) 0"
```

You can also do the same thing with `fun`, but `definition` is the more low-level tool. Note that `definition` does not add the function definition theorem `new_list_def` as a simplifier rule; you can do this by writing `declare new_list_def [simp]`.

## Possibility 3

You can combine possibility 2 with the builtin function `take` to ensure that you *always* get a list of length *exactly* `n`, even when the input list is longer (it is then possibly truncated):

```
definition new_list :: "nat ⇒ nat list ⇒ nat list" where
  "new_list n l = take n l @ replicate (n - length l) 0"
```

## Summary

In the first two cases, you can prove the theorems

```
length l ≤ n ⟹ length (new_list n l) = n
take (length l) (new_list n l) = l
```

(in the first case by induction using `new_list.induct`; in the second case just by unfolding the definition and simplifying)

In the third case, you can prove

```
length (new_list n l) = n
take (length l) (new_list n l) = take n l
```

Obviously, if `length l ≤ n`, the first two and the last one coincide completely.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is: `replicate n (0::nat)` using the function `replicate` of Isabelle/HOL's library.

If you want to implement the function yourself via `fun` then do what you should always do in functional programming ;) try to split your problem into smaller problems that can be solved recursively:

```
fun newlist :: "nat => nat list"
where
  "newlist 0 = []" -- "the only list of length 0*)
| "newlist (Suc n) = ..." -- "use result for 'n' to obtain result for 'n+1'"
```